# Proof Verification: $T$ is injective iff $\ker(T) = \{0_V\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I was given this question in my introductory linear algebra class:

> Given a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow \tilde{V}$, Prove that $T$ is injective iff $\ker(T) = \{0_V\}$.

I came up with the following proof:

---

Let us assume to the contradictory that $T$ is not injective even though $\ker(T) =\{0_V\}$. Then there exist $u, v \in V$ such that $T(u) = T(v)$ for $u \neq v$. We write $u = v +x$ for some $x \in V$, $x \neq 0$. Thus, $$T(u) = T(u+x)$$
$$T(u) = T(u) + T(x)$$
$$T(u) + (-T(u)) = T(u) + T(x) + (-T(u))$$
$$0_{\tilde{V}} = T(x) + 0_{\tilde{V}}$$
$$0_{\tilde{V}} = T(x)$$

Since $\ker(T) = \{0_V\}$, it follows that $x = 0_V$. However this is a contradiction which implies that $u = v$.

Hence our assumption is incorrect and $T$ must be injective.

To prove that $T$ cannot be injective if $\ker(T) \neq \{0_V\}$, we take $k \in V$ such that $T(k) = 0_{\tilde{V}}$ and $k \neq 0_V$, then repeat a similar procedure till we get a contradiction.

---

Is this proof correct? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Essentially correct, but appears a bit convoluted because you essentially made a direct proof and wrapped it up into an unneeded additional layer in order to obtain an indirect proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is almost correct! The one weird part is

> To prove that $T$ cannot be injective if $\ker(T) \neq \{0_V\}$, we take $k \in V$ such that $T(k) = 0_{\tilde{V}}$ and $k \neq 0_V$, then repeat a similar procedure till we get a contradiction.

Remember how we prove implications like "$T$ cannot be injective if $\ker(T) \neq \{0\}$": we assume that $\ker(T) \neq \{0\}$, and we try to deduce that $T$ is not injective. So indeed, the correct thing to do is pick $k \in V$ such that $T(k) = 0_{\widetilde{V}}$ and $k \neq 0_V$. Now we have two elements of $V$ ($k$ and $0_V$) which are not equal but have the same image under $T$, and therefore $T$ is not injective. It's unclear what you mean by "repeat a similar procedure till we get a contradiction" -- for example, this proof did not use contradiction.

There's also one typo / mixup: if you wanted to get $T(u) = T(u+x)$, you should have defined $v = u + x$, not $u = v + x$.

If you don't mind, I'll also make a couple small notes on style:

1. The first half of your proof (showing that $T$ is injective if $\ker(T) = 0$) is secretly a direct proof in disguise! The direct version of this proof is a bit shorter and cleaner, so it might be worthwhile to think about.
2. Don't say "write $u = v + x$ for *some* $x \in V \setminus \{0\}$", because this misleads the reader. We actually know exactly what $x$ is! Instead, say something like "let $x = u - v$ so that $u = v + x$, and note that $x \neq 0_V$".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach, suppose $KerT ={0}$ and suppose $T(u) = T(v)$ then it implies that $T(u-v) = 0$. Since kernel consists only $0$ vector we must have $u=v$. So $T$ is injective.

Suppose $T$ is injective then consider $u \in KerT$ and we know that $T(u) = 0 = T(0)$, since $T$ is injective we have $u=0$ and consequently $KerT$ consists only $0$ vector.